# Como eu faço para capturar outros usuário logado numa aplicação ASP Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Esse código eu consigo capturar um usuário logado

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    public string Name => _accessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

    public IEnumerable<Claim> GetClaimsIdentity()
    {
        return _accessor.HttpContext.User.Claims;
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated()
    {
        return _accessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
```

Mas eu quero capturar não só o usuário que eu estou logado, mas outro que estiver em outro navegador.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se existe essa funcionalidade, pois precisei de algo parecido a alguns anos e não encontrei. O que pode ser feito é tratar isso manualmente, armazenando em algum local o momento que o usuario fizer login e o momento que ele deslogar. Mesmo assim, voce não tem certeza se ele realmente esta ativo, pois ele pode nunca deslogar, entao voce pode tambem fazer um Middleware que registre as requisições, assim voce tem  cada atividade do usuario.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Acredito que não há uma forma de você ter acesso à um usuário logado em outra sessão da sua aplicação, pois isso seria uma falha de segurança séria.

Mas, talvez você possa criar uma instância de Lista de Usuários, determinar o escopo dela como um Singleton e deixá-la pública na aplicação. Toda vez que houver o login de um usuário, você o adiciona na lista e todos terão acesso à esta informação. Mas com certeza isso não seria uma prática saudável.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).